# Scalar Yukawa theory, contraction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, operators, correlation-functions, wick-theorem

In the scalar Yukawa theory ($\Phi$ is real scalar field and $\phi$ is a complex scalar field):
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}_{S Y}=\left(|\partial \phi|^{2}-m^{2}|\phi|^{2}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left((\partial \Phi)^{2}-M^{2} \Phi^{2}\right)-y|\phi|^{2} \Phi,
\end{equation}

I would like to calculate tree-level amplitude for  $\Phi \phi \rightarrow \Phi \phi$.

So the first order is $\lambda^2$ and I have to calculate the contraction

\begin{equation*}
    <0\mid T[ \Phi_1 \phi_2 \phi(x) \overline{\phi}(x) \Phi(x) \phi(y) \overline{\phi}(y) \Phi(y) \Phi_3 \phi_4  ]\mid 0> = \text{ Normal ordering + contraction.}
\end{equation*}

My idea was

[image: Wick]

Which give the $s$-channel.
But then I'm left with the contraction  $\phi \phi$ for my internal propagator.
And I though the contraction of $\phi \phi$ or $\overline{\phi}\overline{\phi}$ gave $0$. Can I contract the two $\phi$ left?  Why can I do that? I do not need to have $\overline{\phi}, \phi,  \Phi$ at each vertex?

Comment: Is it possible because it is the internal propagator so it is not a real particle?

Comment: For the outgoing $\phi$ particle you should have $\overline{\phi}_2$ inside the expectation value, since it is acting on the bra. You are effectively computing $\Phi \overline{\phi} \rightarrow \Phi \phi$ scattering, and finding that it is zero by charge conservation.